# JavaScript - Function not executing properly

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Messenger</title>
</head>
<body onload="checkcookie(); update();">
<div id="whitebg"></div>
<div id="loginbox">
<h1>Pick a username:</h1>
<p><input type="text" name="pickusername" id="cusername" placeholder="Pick a username" class="msginput"></p>
<p class="buttonp"><button onclick="chooseusername()">Choose Username</button></p>
</div>
<div class="msg-container">
    <div class="header">Messenger</div>
    <div class="msg-area" id="msg-area"></div>
    <div class="bottom"><input type="text" name="msginput" class="msginput" id="msginput" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) sendmsg()" value="" placeholder="Enter your message here ... (Press enter to send message)"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var msginput = document.getElementById("msginput");

  function showLogin() {
    document.getElementById("whitebg").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("loginbox").style.display = "inline-block";
  }

    function hideLogin() {
    document.getElementById("whitebg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loginbox").style.display = "none";
  }

  function chooseusername() {
    var user = document.getElementById("cusername").value;
    document.cookie = "messengerUname" + user;
    checkcookie();
  }

  function checkcookie() {
    if(document.cookie.indexOf("messageUname") == -1) {
      showLogin();
    } else {
      hideLogin();
    }
  }

  function getcookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
  }

  function sendmsg() {
    var message = msginput.value;
    if(message != "") {

      var username = getcookie("messengerUname");

      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
          console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
      }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","update-messages.php?username="+username+"&message="+message, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am having is, when I set a username and click the 'Choose Username' button, the hideLogin() function does not execute. You can see the website [here](http://devconnect.comxa.com)

I am using 000webhost to host it. Another problem is that when I type in `sendmsg()` in the console, it says that sendmsg isn't defined

Comment: Tooooooooo lllllloooooooooooooonnnnnnnngggggggggggg!!! Read [ask]!

Comment: please post only the useful code, we do not need your style sheet

Comment: Please post just a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) not everything you have.

Comment: Typo: You have `"messageUname"` instead of `"messengerUname"`. Use a variable so that you'll at least get a *ReferenceError* when you mistype it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, why would it execute?

You do not call it in your choose login function, and do not write `"messageUname"` in your cookie

Though the error is probably there:

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf("messageUname") == -1) {
```

since all your other functions mention `"messengerUname"`, i suppose that's a simple typo.

replace `"messageUname"` with `"messengerUname"` and you should be good

(never did javascript so i might be wrong)